# SSMS Intellisense works for some schema and does not work for other

Tags: intellisense, database-schema, sql-server-2016

I have a remote SQL Server 2016 database and SQL Server Management Studio 2016. The database already had some schemas for which intellisense works perfectly. I created a new schema and few tables under the new schema. For this new schema, intellisense does not work at all. After creating new schema, intellisense works for schemas which were already there. I have ensured that the intellisense is enabled at

```
Tools > Options > Text Editor > Transact-SQL > Intellisense > Enable Intellisense
```

I have also refreshed the local cache by hitting

<kbd>Ctrl + Shift + R</kbd>

on keyboard and clicking

```
Edit > Intellisense > Refresh Local Cache
```

several times. It is really strange why intellisense does not work only for one particular schema.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Would be curious to see if everything is organized hierarchically, e.g. with the 1 MB limit in place, add a new schema called `aaa` and see if those objects appear and others get kicked off the other end... might be hitting the 1 MB limit as it generates the arrays alphabetically (though it may lose it by age too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as a hit and trial under following menu item,

```
Tools > Options > Text Editor > Intellisense
```

I changed **Maximum script size** from ***1 MB*** to ***Unlimited***. And it worked like a charm.